# Swift func sorted() -> [Element]

Tags: swift, sorting

What is the algorithm used by Swift function sorted() -> [Element] in the standard library for [Int]?
[sorted()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945003-sorted)

I tested some integer arrays and found that the performance of sorted() is much worse than bucket sort.

Comment: You view the source code at swift.org

Comment: How did you test? For example in a Playground or in the simulator in Debug scheme tests are not significant.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, I found the source code at /stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift

Comment: @vadian I tested in command-line swift without compiling.